# javascript inside window.document.write is not working

Tags: windows

I've the below code inside a chrome extension button click:

```js
var opened = window.open("");
opened.document.write("<html><head></head><body bgcolor=\"Bisque\"><button  onclick=\"onSaveToDBClick()\" style=\"position:absolute;left:40px;top:200px\" size=\"40\" name=\"datapushbutton\">Save To DataBase</button>"+ 
   "<script>"+
  "function onSaveToDBClick(){"+
   "alert(\"hello\");"+
   "}"+
   "<\/script>"+
  "</body></html>");
  opened.document.close();
```

when i click the chromeextension button a window with 'Save To Database' button is shown up.But when i click on 'Save To Database' button no alert is shown.

Please Help me out.

Comment: Where do you start the script?

Comment: I couldn't understand what it meant by 'start the script'..please re-ask..

Comment: I couldn't see the `<script>` tag before

Comment: Actually what my requirement is to handle the click event of button added in the html page created by window.document.write..For this purpose i chose javascript. Am i wrong...If i'm write i've to write to handle the click event with 'onclick' attribute of button control and <script> function ....</script> of javascript.correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: NieDzejkob - did i answer your question correctly..?